# Is it secure to create API in Django without Rest Framework?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I've created an app in my Django project which works the same as API.
But for post requests, logins I'm doing something like this.

request "GET"(URL: example.com/api/get) this returns a `csrftoken` which is then used by my applications as a cookie.

request "POST"(URL: example.com/api/login), Here the frontend application logs in the user. The `csrftoken` from `example.com/api/get` is used in cookies and the same is used as `csrfmiddlewaretoken` in post data.

My question here is, it is secure to create an API like this and use it instead of **Django RestFramework**.
Any suggestion will be appreciated.
THANK YOU

Comment: Is the URL that returns the CSRF token responds to everyone? If so it's not secure at all because everyone can get tokens and send requests to other endpoints. The better approach will be that if a user logs in you'll send back the token if it's authenticated. And for other endpoints, they should send the token in cookies.

Comment: @Shayan It is possible to get a CSRF token via that URL for everyone, because without a CSRF token POST request is not possible, and without POST request no one can log in. Even if I create a function to send the email & password via GET request that will make it totally open to the world.

Comment: It's not the best practice but you can change the token after logging in. Users can see the token and change it and that makes it vulnerable. Try reading [this article](https://www.pyscoop.com/write-json-apis-in-pure-django-for-beginners/) it may help you. You should use Django built-in decorators.